# Limit calculation, calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find

$$  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{\alpha x} -e^{\beta x}}{\sin(\alpha x) + \sin(\beta x) }$$

but dont have a clue where to start, could someone give me a hint please ?

Comment: what kind of numbers are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: They should be both real random numbers

Comment: are you sure that $x$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: If you don't at least restrict them to, say, positive numbers, I'm pretty sure this won't have a general answer.   $e^{ax}$ has very different behavior if $a>0$ or $a<0$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sorry, it was a typo, x tends to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\alpha \neq -\beta$

$$e^{\alpha x} = 1 + \alpha x + o(x)$$
$$e^{\beta x} = 1 + \beta x + o(x)$$
$$\sin(\alpha x) = \alpha x + o(x)$$
$$\sin(\beta x) = \beta x + o(x)$$
So
$$ \frac{e^{\alpha x} -e^{\beta x}}{\sin(\alpha x) + \sin(\beta x) } = \dfrac{1 + \alpha x - 1- \beta x +o(x)}{\alpha x + \beta x +o(x) } = \dfrac{\alpha - \beta + \dfrac{o(x)}{x}}{\alpha + \beta + \dfrac{o(x)}{x}} \to \dfrac{\alpha - \beta}{\alpha + \beta}$$

Alternatively, use

$$\frac{e^{\alpha x} -e^{\beta x}}{\sin(\alpha x) + \sin(\beta x) } 
=\frac{\dfrac{e^{\alpha x} - 1}{\alpha x}\alpha-\dfrac{e^{\beta x} - 1}{\beta x}\beta}{\dfrac{\sin(\alpha x)}{\alpha x }\alpha + \dfrac{\sin(\beta x)}{\beta x}\beta }$$

and $\lim \dfrac{e^{\alpha x} - 1}{\alpha x} = \lim \dfrac{e^{\beta x} - 1}{\beta x} = \lim \dfrac{\sin(\alpha x)}{\alpha x } = \lim \dfrac{\sin(\beta x)}{\beta x} = 1 $

Answer (score 0):

The expression makes sense only if $\alpha\neq-\beta$, and if it is the case, you can simply apply l'Hopital's rule (if you want only a hint, stop reading now):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\alpha x}-e^{\beta x}}{\sin(\alpha x)+\sin(\beta x)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\alpha e^{\alpha x}-\beta e^{\beta x}}{\alpha\cos(\alpha x)+\beta\cos(\beta x)}\\
&=\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha+\beta}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Using Wolfram Alpha:

lim (e^(alpha x)-e^(beta x))/(sin(alpha x)+sin(\beta x)) as x->0

Answer:

(alpha-beta)/(alpha+beta)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28e%5E%28alpha+x%29-e%5E%28beta+x%29%29%2F%28sin%28alpha+x%29%2Bsin%28%5Cbeta+x%29%29+as+x-%3E0

Comment: Reasong for downvoting: I think that the OP is more interested in the method than the particular limit value.